# Hibernate returning null for one to many relation if junit test is wrapped transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a one to many relation where the "children" are fetched lazy. If running a junit test with this setup i will run into a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - i've looked for tons of possible solutions (I am not willing to set fetch type to eager only to test stuff more easy)

However, if I annotate my test as @Transactional I will not get the error, but it will return null for the entities children.

I somehow understand the lazy fetch exception, but if i'm within the same transaction, why can't i lazy fetch the stuff? Example:

```
@Transactional
@Test
public function test() {
  ParentEntity parentEntity = parentEntityService.read(requestContext, p.getId());
  Set<ChildEntity> childEntitites = parentEntity.getChildren();

  Assert.assertNotNull(childEntities); // will fail
}
```

The same without @Transactional will cause lazy fetch exception. I've already treid using

- Hibernate.initialize() on the parentEntity after raeding it
- getting an instance of entityManager and opening and closing transactions manually

Any ideas?

** EDIT **

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PARENTENTITY")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "SEQ_PARENTENTITY")
public class ParentEntity extends BaseEntity{

    @Getter @Setter
    @NotNull @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="STRING_1")
    private String string1;

    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENTENTITY_ID", updatable = false)
    @JsonView(View.DetailView.class)
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;
}
```

Comment: Must be a bug in ParentEntity: Hibernate will never initialize a collection to null. We need more code.

Comment: Added the parent Entity

Comment: children has null as its default value. Hibernate will set it to a non-null collection, but if your service is the one creating the returned instance of ParentEntity, then it will be null.

Comment: Ths seems to be the right answer - i removed transactional so that the service is not creating and reading the entities in the same transaction.

Comment: That's not the proper fix. Your entity should be initialized in a correct state: a non-null set of chilren.

Comment: How can i achieve this?

Comment: `private Set<ChildEntity> children = new HashSet<>();`